# How to find the mean value of columns in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a SAS data set, let's say:

```
No d1 d2 d3 ... dn
1  2  3  4 ... n1
2  3  4  5 ... n2
3  4  5  6 ... n3
```

I now need to find the averages of all columns in SAS.
Is there a way to do it?

The number of columns is not specific.
If I need the averages of `d1`-`dn` columns, then the output I expect is:

```
3 4 5 ..  (n1+n2+n3)/3
```

Is there a way to do this Either in the data step or using proc sql or proc iml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming all your required variables begin with d, then you can use the colon wildcard operator to select them all.  I've used PROC SUMMARY here, this is identical to PROC MEANS with the NOPRINT option.  Obviously this is a very minor alteration of the answer from @pteranodon

```
proc summary data=have nway;
var d: ;
output out=want (drop=_:) mean=;
run;
```

Answer (score 6):

`proc means` is the way to calculate column-wise statistics.

```
data have;
  input No d1 d2 d3 d4;
datalines;
1  2  8 60 80
2  3  12 50 70
3  4  10 40 60
;
run;

proc means data=have noprint nway;
  var d1-d4;
  output 
    out=want(drop=_TYPE_ _FREQ_) 
    mean=;
run;
```

The drop= clause will exclude the automatic variables for type and frequency if you don't need them.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in a data step you would use something like this `mean(OF d1-d100)`. Note the `of` inside the function. It is a symbolic reference saying *calculate mean of d1, d2, d3, ..., d100 columns*

Comment: I think the OP wants column means across observations, not mean of columns within each observation. The sample data gives the same results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PROC MEANS, eg,

```
PROC MEANS DATA = indata; 
VAR d1-dn; 
OUTPUT=outdata MEAN=m1-mn; 
RUN;
```

Comment: What if I dont know the value of n and it keeps changing?

Comment: Back of the envelope, I'd use PROC CONTENTS to output a dataset with my variable names, then use CALL SYMPUT (http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2007/050-2007.pdf) to produce a macro variable with all my d1 - dn. You might want to transpose the data first... I'd have to double check. Anyway, there might be a better way... but if I only wanted to think about it for a minute or two and wasn't necessarily looking for the best way to handle it, just one that is simple and will work, outfiling PROC CONTENTS and building a macro variable with CALL SYMPUT would be my approach